# Rails How to bypass require in strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass params without required parameter like below.

```
def str_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name)
end
```

And pass param without user key

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to pass key, you can directly remove require like below

```
params.permit(:id, :name)
```

Comment: What if I need this case for single action and other actions need require key

Comment: you can create 2 separate methods 

1) with key 2) without key. call that method as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get params in controller like `params[:id]` or `params[:name]`.

It will bypass strong params. But using strong params is always recommended.

So the best would be to put `params.permit(:id, :name)` instead of `params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name)`

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: When your request contains root key `:user`, use it like this:

```
PERMITTED_PARAMS = %i[id name].freeze

def action_name
  puts str_params
end

def str_params
  params.require(:user).permit(*PERMITTED_PARAMS)
end
```

Case 2: When request contains user attributes at top level, without any nesting under `:user` key:

```
def action_name
  # puts params.permit(*PERMITTED_PARAMS)
end
```